# Is it possible (or advisable) to do a retrospective git flow release?

Tags: git, git-flow

I've been developing a project for more than a few releases now, before discovering git flow.

For consistency's sake with future development, I'd like to tag past commits as 1.0, 1.1, etc releases.

My Git-fu is not the greatest, so I'll be using Source Tree to assist me here. I see you can select a past commit when selecting "New Release" but will this do as I want?

It's also possible that I may misunderstand fundamentally misunderstand what releases are; from a git flow perspective I understand it as branches created from develop, then tagged, then merged back to both develop and master.

So say I'm about to release 3.0 here, but I want to release 1.0, 1.1, and 2.0 retrospectively:

```
tags                1.0   1.1   2.0   3.0
master  __*__*__*____.__.__.__.__.__.__.  no commits for a long time
release             /     /     /     /  
develop __*__*__*__/\_*__/\_*__/\_*__/    commits all the way along
commits   a  b  c     x     y     z
```

Can I / should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To both questions:

> Can I do this?

If your master already contains the commits that you'd like to include in release 1.0, 1.1, and 2.0, no. You'll get `Already up-to-date` as a response from git when you try to create merges from the release branches.

> Should I do this?

If all you'd like to do is make sure that you have tags that indicate your releases, no. Just create a new tag at the commit that *would* have been the merge from the tagged release branch.

```
Jeremy@localhost ~/git-test master
$ git log --oneline
afcc012 Submodule commit.
45926a2 Second.
a5c809b Initial.

Jeremy@localhost ~/git-test master
$ git tag 1.1 45926a2

Jeremy@localhost ~/git-test master
$ git tag
1.1
```

Then start git flowing from here on!

By the way, if you've been getting along fine without some kind of release management of your branches, git flow might be a bit overkill for you. When working with small teams or on my own, I find that [GitHub flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) is a bit more appropriate.

Comment: Ah, nice one. I did a test, and sure enough up my tags popped in the releases section in Github. So tags are just references to commits then, and by creating a release branch, you're just committing in isolation in readiness for a final tagged commit, then merge back to dev and master? Makes perfect sense now. Thanks for helping me both practically and conceptually!

Comment: That's exactly right. Release branches are there to make sure that everything's nice and clean. Don't forget to merge master onto your release branch before merging back in--you never know what hotfixes have been put on master since the dev forks.

Comment: And, if you want to be git-technical, _branches_ are just pointers to commits, as well. They're pretty much tags with the ability to move.

Comment: I truly envy people who find git easier than I do! Thanks again for you help :)